# Configure errors

Tags: macos, configure

Mac OS X

I do configure and then make my odbc binary.

That is configure command:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -D par1=1024" --enable-pthreads --with-iodbc=/usr/local/iODBC --with-libpq=$pg_dir
```

But the result is:

```
...
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
./configure: line 4506: syntax error near unexpected token `with,'
./configure: line 4506: `PGAC_ARG_REQ(with, odbcver,'
make: *** [config.status] Error 2
...
```

What is the reason and what to check and fix?

I run

> autoconf

```
----------
autoconf
aclocal.m4:21: warning: this file was generated for autoconf 2.68.
You have another version of autoconf.  It may work, but is not guaranteed to.
If you have problems, you may need to regenerate the build system entirely.
To do so, use the procedure documented by the package, typically `autoreconf'.
configure.ac:331: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:197: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2598: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2608: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:331: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
../../lib/autoconf/lang.m4:197: AC_LANG_CONFTEST is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2598: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2608: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:643: AS_IF is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2598: _AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
../../lib/autoconf/general.m4:2608: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:64: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
```

Comment: That looks like Autoconf _input_ being executed.  Where did you get `configure`?

Comment: You need to use `autoconf` as stated above...

Comment: The *configure is in the same dir where source codes. I have a .sh script which does configure, make and copy *.so to the target location. It was created by other developer.

Comment: How to use autoconf? What to change?

Comment: In your project root try using `autoconf` and see if it works; if not you'll need to install it. You can compile it yourself or use something like `MacPorts`.

Comment: Run it without parameters?

Comment: Yes, no parameters. It can't hurt anything — and to see if you actually have `autoconf` on your system. What is the project you are trying to compile? (link might be useful).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167917/discussion-between-oleg-and-lll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one of reasons is: the macro PGAC_ARG_REQ and some other were undefined, I have found the *.m4, copied and it works.

Thanks l'L'l for the great help!